# How to use 'One word invocation name in actions on google'

Tags: actions-on-google

I am building an action on google[], for which I have decided one word invocation name - Mate.
On using any one word invocation name, I am facing error "Could not reserve your pronunciation 'Mate' because: Your Action's display name must contain more than one word, or more than one word and a prefix (such as "the" or "an"). " on google assistant console.
How can I use only one word invocation name for my action?

As per the actions documentation https://developers.google.com/actions/policies/general-policies#name_requirements, it says "One-word names are not allowed, unless the name is unique to your brand or trademark within the target country. Instructions to request an exception for individual countries are below."
But the process is not defined to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The procedure *is* listed further down on the page, where it says

> We will consider exceptions to certain naming policies on a case-by-case basis; you can request an exception filling out [this form](https://developers.google.com/actions/support/?requesttype=appnamewhitelist) and requesting an Action Name Whitelist.

However, you are unlikely to get the exception.

In addition to the restriction you noted against one-word names, there is also the rule that states

> A name uniquely identifies your Action, so it must distinguish itself from other Actions and from features of the Assistant. We don’t allow names that are:
>
> - Common phrases (for example, thank you, how are you?, good morning)

While I am not on Google's review team, I strongly suspect that "mate" would be considered a common word or phrase.

The only criteria that I suspect would get you the name was if you also controlled "mate.com", or another major domain, and had gone through [brand verification](https://developers.google.com/actions/console/connecting-properties).

Comment: Thank you. Sent the request to get action name whitelist to google actions support team